# Link to a file outside public repository on Github

Tags: html, github, repository

I recently created a webpage using Github pages. Since I don't have a paid account, the repository necessarily needs to be kept public. I'm okay with this, except for some .jpeg files which I would like to store in a different, private repository. When I did this and tried to provide a link to this file on the webpage, it didn't work.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If the images are going to be on a public website, it doesn't make sense why you'd want to put the images in a private repository. And if you have a private repository, why aren't you putting your website there?

Comment: @RichardHunter Like I mentioned, the Github pages repository cannot be made private (unless you have a paid account). Sure, some of the the images will be available on public website. But my question is the following: I have a private repo with images, some of which I want to include on the website. Is there a way to link to them from the public Githubpages repo?

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain their reason for the downvote? Would certainly help when posting my next question.

Comment: You say you don't have a private repository, but then you appear to say that you do have one, where you are going to store the images. This seems like an obvious contradiction, so I think you should try and make it clearer in your question what this means.

Comment: Just to clarify that there is no contradiction here: there are two repositories, one private and one public. The private repo is where the image files are stored. The public repo is where all the files for the webpage are stored. This webpage is hosted on Github pages, and the repo *needs* to be kept public (Github pages won't let you make it private unless you have a paid account).

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a [GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/quickstart) like [Deploy to GitHub Pages](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-github-pages) which introduces a build step workflow.

That step can have the necessary secret to access your private repository and fetch the `.jpeg` files you need to add them to the built repository.
But that means those files would be stored in the publication branch of your public repository.

From a public repository, you would not be able to just "add a link" to a private repository resource, without embedding in one way or another a secret token allowing you to access said private repository.